# How to add 0x padding to a uintptr_t in a variable?

Tags: c++, hex, cout

So I'm trying to figure out how can I add `0x` padding to a `uintptr_t`. The current value of it is: `400000`.

However I would like it to be `0x400000`. So currently to achieve this I am adding the `0x` padding when I'm printing this out. However how would I go about this so I can store the padded value of `uintprt_t`?

```
uintptr_t modBase = GetModuleBaseAddress(pID, "ac_client.exe");
cout << "0x" << hex << modBase <<endl; //Output is 0x400000
```

The reason for trying to achieve this is that later I would like to find a dynamic base address as shown here:

```
uintptr_t dynamicBaseAddress = modBase + 0x10f4f4;
cout << "DynamicBaseAddress is: " << dynamicBaseAddress << endl; // Again var is missing 0x
```

And again the result is: `50f4f4` without the padding.

Comment: You can not store meta-information about how you want to display some value inside of that value. Either write a class that does formatting or continue using << "0x" << std::hex everywhere you want to output hex.

Comment: `std::cout << std::showbase << std::hex << value` will show it, but it's more typing.

Comment: You seem to ve confused.  Values and their presentation are not the same thing.  A picture of a person is not the person.  This is like asking how you could make a person sepia toned; that is a property of the photograph, not the person usually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the expression printed in both cases is `uintptr_t`, so in both cases output stream behaves the same way, i.e. not add the prefix. As an alternative to @RetiredNinja's suggestion in the comments (use `std::showbase`), you could create a wrapper type with a custom `operator<<` which would allow you to implement the way the information is printed regardless of the current state of the stream (i.e. changing back to decimal in between wouldn't change, how the value is printed).

This does require you to implement operators for operations you want to be available for this type though:

```
class UintptrWrapper
{
public:
    UintptrWrapper(uintptr_t value)
        : m_value(value)
    {
    }

    // + operation should work, so we need to implement it
    friend UintptrWrapper operator+(UintptrWrapper const& summand1, UintptrWrapper const& summand2)
    {
        return { summand1.m_value + summand2.m_value };
    }

    // custom printing of info
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, UintptrWrapper const& value)
    {
        auto oldFlags = s.flags();
        s << "0x" << std::hex << value.m_value;
        s.flags(oldFlags);
        return s;
    }
private:
    uintptr_t m_value;
};
```

```
UintptrWrapper modBase = 0x400000;
std::cout << modBase << '\n';

auto dynamicBaseAddress = modBase + 0x10f4f4; // result is another UintptrWrapper with the same behaviour when writing to the stream as above
std::cout << "DynamicBaseAddress is: " << dynamicBaseAddress << '\n';
```

Output:

```
0x400000
DynamicBaseAddress is: 0x50f4f4
```